# How to create multiple login access with different database in yii2?

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

Hello i am creating web reporting administration for my company. There are 3 database login, so i need to make 3 different login function. The problem is when login the application is trying to findidentity with every class that implement identityInterface. 
For Example i have

```
FORM A -> Login to Mysql
FORM B -> Login to Postgresql
FORM C -> Login to Mysql
```

when i login to using Form A the other FORM B and FORM C is also logged in.

here is my configuration

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'defaultRoute' => 'web',
    'components' => ['urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [],
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'vOVnTnH6zKE10R21oPfSz81DELj0W9GK',
            'enableCsrfValidation'=>true,
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'loginUrl' => 'site/login',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\web\Admin',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'loginUrl' => 'adminfaspay',
        ],
        'member' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\web\Member',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'loginUrl' => 'web/dochecklogin',
        ],
        'merchant' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\report\Merchant',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'loginUrl' => 'home/login',
        ],

        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file basename(path)y default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
        'db2' => require(__DIR__ . '/dbmssql.php'),
        'db3' => require(__DIR__ . '/dbmsorcl.php'),
        'db4' => require(__DIR__ . '/dbmsmysql.php'),
        'db5' => require(__DIR__ . '/dbposgre.php'),
    ],

    'timeZone' => 'UTC',
    'params' => $params,
    'modules' => [
        'gridview' => [
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module'
        // enter optional module parameters below - only if you need to
        // use your own export download action or custom translation
        // message source
        // 'downloadAction' => 'gridview/export/download',
        // 'i18n' => []
        ]
    ],
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}

return $config;
```

My Member.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models\web;
use Yii;

use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\Security;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class Member extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $authKey;

    public static function getDb()
    {
        return \Yii::$app->db5;  // use the "db2" application component
    }

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'member_merchant';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['email', 'password'], 'required']
        ];
    }
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'User id',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'password' => 'Password'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
              $users = self::find()
                ->where(["id" => $id])
                ->one();
        return $users;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param  string      $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($email) {

        $users = self::find()
                ->where(["email" => $email])
                ->one();

        if (!count($users)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $users;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param  string  $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === sha1($password);
    }
}
```

Admin.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models\web;
use Yii;

use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\Security;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class Admin extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $authKey;

    public static function getDb()
    {
        return \Yii::$app->db5;  // use the "db2" application component
    }

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'admin';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'password'], 'required']
        ];
    }
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'User id',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password'
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
              $users = self::find()
                ->where(["id" => $id])
                ->one();
        return $users;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param  string      $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username) {

        $users = self::find()
                ->where(["username" => $username])
                ->one();

        if (!count($users)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $users;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param  string  $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === sha1($password);
    }
}
```

Merchant.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models\report;
use Yii;

use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\Security;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class Merchant extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $authKey;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'usys.usex';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['passwd', 'user_uid'], 'required']
        ];
    }
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'user_uid' => 'User id',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password'
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
              $users = self::find()->with('userGroups')->with('userBois')
                ->where(["usex_uid" => $id])
                ->one();
        return $users;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param  string      $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username) {
        $users = self::find()
                ->where(["user_uid" => $username])
                ->one();

        if (!count($users)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $users;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->usex_uid;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param  string  $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->passwd === $password;
    }

    public function getUserGroups()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserGroup::className(), ['usex_uid' => 'usex_uid']);
    }

    public function getUserBois()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserBoi::className(), ['usex_uid' => 'usex_uid']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specialize your classes in order to return the correct database instance (getDB) depending on the database you wish to access.
For example, you can do so by invoking an action differentiated by the various 'login' and in this action to assign an object to the correct database instance that interests you.

Comment: any example? i dont really understand what u're saying